# Mass difference of $B^0$, $\overline{B^0}$-states

Tags: quantum-mechanics, particle-physics, neutrinos, weak-interaction

It is known that $B^0$, $\overline{B^0}$ or $K^0$, $\overline{K^0}$ particles have different masses and that they oscillate in 'an equivalent' way to neutrino oscillations.

Is it theoretically calculable, why $B^0$ and $\overline{B^0}$ have different masses and how large this mass difference actually is?

Is the reason for the mass difference the same reason why neutrinos (presumably) have different masses?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, the neutral mesons you mentioned do oscillate, as you mentioned, at very short distance scales, analogously to neutrino oscillations, which oscillate at distance scales of hundreds miles. (Actually, the *B* mesons you mentioned are the [bottom-strange ones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%E2%80%93Bbar_oscillation), [*B*<sub>s</sub>](https://pdg.lbl.gov/2020/tables/rpp2020-tab-mesons-bottom-strange.pdf). )

There are estimates of the relevant mass difference, computed from the "box diagram" of the Standard model, and involving two *W*s, and the CKM-flavor violating matrix elements. But, beware: $B^0_s$, $\overline{B}_s^0$,   $K^0$, $\overline{K}^0$ are not the ones with different masses, anymore than the $\nu_{e,\mu,\tau}$ are!

The  propagating states are linear combinations of them, with differing masses, in both cases. Nobody can calculate such mass differences for neutrinos, by contrast; those are just determined by experiment.

That is, $$|K_0\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt 2} \left ( |K_S\rangle+ |K_L\rangle\right ),\\
|\bar K_0\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt 2} \left ( |K_S\rangle - |K_L\rangle\right ), $$
where L indicates the long-lived CP odd mass eigenstate, and S the dramatically shorter-lived  CP even one. Similarly for the *B*s.

For the Kaons, of mass roughly half a GeV, the relevant mass difference proportional to the oscillation frequency is
$$ \Delta m\approx 3\cdot 10^{-15}\hbox{ GeV}. $$

For the *B*<sub>s</sub>, of mass roughly 5.366 GeV,
the relevant frequency/ mass difference is
$$
\Delta m\approx 1.17 \cdot 10^{-8} \hbox{MeV}\\
 \approx 18\cdot 10^{12} \hbar /s ,
$$
dubbed 18 /ps in natural units. This corresponds to oscillation lengths of  20 μm, so, a far cry from kilometers for neutrinos!

Comment: Thanks a lot. But why isn't it possible to use analogous box-diagrams to estimate the mass difference of neutrinos.

Comment: Neutrinos are elementary and they get their masses either from Yukawa couplings, or other mysterious sources. They (probably) don't oscillate to antineutrinos. Mesons are composite, and their quarks annihilate with their antiquarks to oscillate to their *antiparticle*. It's a "just so" thing...